# How can pass the request parameter as a formdata in dart or flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, form-data

I have tried many formats to pass the request parameter in the flutter project but I'm getting API status code 415 and `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)`.
I have added the postman image for the understanding of the form data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you post the dart code you used?

Comment: I have added the source code image

Comment: you can use dio library for your http call. It is too porwerful to handle every exceptions.
https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Comment: Thanks @GourangoSutradhar for the response but I don't want to use the dio library. please help me on this HTTP library.

Answer (score 1):

For Flutter HTTP library it goes like this,

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(''));
request.bodyFields = {
  'firstName': 'Keval',
  'lastName': 'ebiz',
  'email': 'al@gmail.com',
  'phone': '1234'
};
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I have implemented your code but again I'm getting 415 status code and "Unsupported Media Type".

Comment: @AlpitPanchal are sending somethings else with the request?

Comment: Thanks, @Srilal after use the"http.MultipartRequest". it's working